# Spyder (Python 3.7) starts with a black window. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

If I click on the place where the menu bar should be, it shows options, but a black window still exists, so this is a real problem.

This is what the problem looks like:

[image: this is what the problem looks like !]

Comment: i installed it using command,  pip install spyder

Comment: pip is a bad friend for spyder, try reinstalling in anaconda package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as EPo said, pip is a bad command to use with Spyder. You should use the Anaconda distribution of python and then you can use the conda command to properly install Spyder. `conda install spyder` will install the latest spyder. I'd also recommend using virtual environments. Tou can create a virtual environment by typing: `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda`. You activate this by typing: `source activate yourenvname`. The necessary comands and methods to use can be found [here](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) and [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).